# Invert bits on even positions from binary number

Tags: c

Say `a` is my number.

And I want `a1` to be a with all bits on even positions inverted.

This is my current solution

```
int a1 = ((a & 0xaaaaaaaa)  | (~(a) & 0x55555555));
```

How can I make this faster?

Comment: Do you have any indication that it is "slow"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the bitwise xor (`^`) operator:

```
a1 ^= 0x55555555;
```

this will invert bits 0, 2, 4, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise xor ^

See [C++ bitwise operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/)

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that does not depend on `int` being 32 bits, (but does depend on an even bit width for `int`):

```
// Use `^` operator as suggested by @unwind
int a1 ^= UINT_MAX/3;
```

Comment: You shouldn't do bitwise operations on signed integers though.

Comment: @Lundin  Agree, bit operations best done on unsigned integer types.  Here, just going with OP's `int` example, but should have mentioned that axiom before.

Comment: @Lundin BTW, I do not think `int a1 ^= UINT_MAX/3` does bitwise operations on signed integers, unlike the top rated answer.  `(int) ^= (unsigned)` --> `(int) = (int) ^ (unsigned)` --> `(int) = (unsigned) ^ (unsigned)` -- > `(int) = (unsigned)`.

Comment: Fair enough, but the last part is still a problem, the result is stored in a signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

The 32 bit solution already given is probably what you want and probably what you should accept as the correct answer. But just because someone wondered what would be the generic solution, I started to ponder on it. Here is a very generic solution, which allows all kind of weird stuff... :)

Please note that this code will be much less effective than a direct XOR on the intended data type.

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum
{
  INVERT_ODD        = 0xAA,
  INVERT_EVEN       = 0x55,
  INVERT_LS_NIBBLES = 0x0F,
  INVERT_MS_NIBBLES = 0xF0,
  ...  // and so on
} invert_pattern_t;

void invert_bits (void* data, size_t size, invert_pattern_t pattern)
{
  uint8_t* byte = data;

  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    byte[i] ^= (uint8_t)pattern;
  }
}
```

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  uint32_t data32 = 0x12345678;

  printf("%.8X ", data32);
  invert_bits(&data32, sizeof(data32), INVERT_EVEN);
  printf("inverted: %.8X\n", data32);
}
```

Comment: Suggest `#include <inttypes.h> printf("%.8" PRIX32, data32);`.